# Why is error contribution higher than factor contribution in ANOVA?

Tags: anova, minitab

I used Taguchi L9 orthogonal array design for my experiment to optimise the tool geometry parameters for better surface roughness. I have conducted experiments as per DOE and I used Minitab to find percentage contribution of each factor on surface roughness. I ended with a 50.21% error contribution. **Can anyone please give your valuable suggestions on why I am getting 50.21% error contribution which is higher than factor contribution?**
Please take a look in the picture and share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in Advance
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You got a high error contribution because your model does not account for that much of the variance in surface roughness.

There are lots of possible reasons for this, here are some (not an exhaustive list):

1. Measurement error. If your variables are measured imperfectly, that will be part of the error contribution.
2. Missing variables. There could be other things that contribute to surface roughness; in fact, there surely are. Models aren't meant to be perfect representations of reality.
3. Nonlinear relationships: Perhaps the relationship between surface roughness and some of your variables isn't linear. In your sample, it surely isn't perfectly linear, but it might not even be close to linear.
4. Sampling error. Even if your model is perfect in the population, it will not be perfect in any random sample. It might even be off by a lot.

All of these contribute to error in linear models. How much do they contribute in your case? You have to do a lot of investigating.  Also, 50% error contribution might not be a lot. What is a "lot" here is field dependent.

Comment: (+1) another one is interactions between the independent variables, although that can be considered nonlineatity.

Comment: @Peter Flom, First of all, thank you very much for your valuable time and explanation. Sir, I would like to add more information to your point 2. Yes, there are other variables such as **Spindle speed. Feed rate, and Depth of cut.** but in this experiment, I kept spindle speed, feed rate and depth of cut as constant and **i would like to know the how the surface roughness varies in regards to the change in cutter geometry parameters ( rake angle, land width and honing radius).**

Comment: @Robert Long, Thank you for your valuable information. Sir, as you and peter flom mentioned it is a non-linear relationship, I would like to know the way I performed the ANOVA is not suitable to my case?

Comment: @DeVa the model you ran is a linear model. If you know the relationship is nonlinear then it would not be suitable unless you make some transformation(s) or perhaps use a different model entirely, with a lot more data !! With 9 observations and 3 factors each with 3 levels, this seems very under-powered to start with.

Comment: @ Rober Long, Sir, In the above figure each experiment represent insert (experiment 1= insert 1) in reality, after conducting 9 tests I got the best result with experiment 8 (insert 8). My aim is to find which insert geometry will gives better surface roughness.  Actually in this study I am trying to compare the results of 9 different inserts with other existing insert. Experiment number 8 ( insert 8) gives better results. now i am trying to perform ANOVA to see is the optimum insert geometry is experiment 8 (insert 8- rake angle 18 degree, land width=0.2mm, honing radius =20 micro meter).

Comment: or a new combination. In ANOVA i got the optimum geometry is ( rake angle 18 degree, land width=0.2mm, honing radius =40 micro meter). My question is : I got 50% error contribution, so does the optimum results i got is right or wrong. how can we signify the optimum condition is right or wrong?  Thank you so much @Rober Long